# Can't see the results using cURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to post and get results from another website but it's not always shown.

This is the post and get code:

```
<?php
$data = array("categoryCode" => $_POST['CELL_PHONES_STORE'], "code" => $_POST['CELL_PHONE_IMEI_ESN'], "imeiEsn" => $_POST['imeiEsn'], "modelCode" => $_POST['APPLA1533IPHONE5S16GBATT'], "program" => $_POST['ATT']);
$url = 'https://atttradein.flipswap.com/api/rest/v2/serialnumbers?='.$data;
$post = curl_init();
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($post);
curl_close($post);
print_r(json_decode($result));

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you get json encoded data back? Maybe the decoding call simply fails? Did you check your http servers error log file for that?

Comment: Also you have to change the way you make your call: you write you want to make a POST call, yet you do not tell curl to do that. Also you cannot simply append an array to the url, what is that meant to give? Instead you have to hand over your data (the array) as a curl option and tell it to make a post request.

Answer (score 1):

Use http_build_query instead of array. More details here http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php.

Answer (score 1):

now im trying  this code

```html
$data = array("categoryCode" => $_POST['CELL_PHONES_STORE'], "code" => $_POST['CELL_PHONE_IMEI_ESN'], "imeiEsn" => $_POST['imeiEsn'], "modelCode" => $_POST['APPLA1533IPHONE5S16GBATT'], "program" => $_POST['ATT'], "referer" => "https://buyback.att.com/");


//set POST variables
$url = 'https://atttradein.flipswap.com/api/rest/v2/serialnumbers?=';


//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://buyback.att.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w+'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);



//close connection
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```